# Record sets and retrieving data using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an On_Click() event within a form that's on an Address. This event changes the type of the address to either Primary or Secondary. A customer can have multiple secondary addresses, but only a single Primary. For this reason, in the On_Click() event, I need to check for a pre-existing address record with type Primary if they want to assign another address as the Primary.

I'm not very familiar with record sets, or how to reference them in VBA, but a colleague suggested that as an option. The customer will have a Cust_ID as well as a Group_ID so I'm wanting to select all Address Types where Cust_ID = X and Group_ID = Y. If a Primary exists, prompt the user with that information and ask if they want to overwrite.

Then I can run a couple of queries to update those records. I'm just not sure how to pull that data to reference it in the first place. I'll need to store each record (index?) in a variable to use in both my prompt and query.

Can you let me know if I'm even on the right track with the following code?

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim addrQry as DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
set rst = addrQry.OpenRecordSet()
```

Comment: Not quite, you're using a null object `addrQry`. Objects must be initialized before used.

Comment: You should be able to do the update in a single query. Something like `Update [tblAddress] set [Primary]=iif([ID]=" & frmID & ","Y","N") where CustomerID=[CustomerID]` or similar. And for checking if there is already a primary, you could use a Dlookup. Just some ideas.